# JavaFX copy to clipboard

Tags: java, javafx

In `Swing` you can use `java.awt.Toolkit` and `java.awt.datatransfer.Clipboard` classes to copy the text value in the system clipboard and I'm looking for a solution to copy the value of a `String` variable to the system clipboard using `JavaFX`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To copy the content of a String variable to the system Clipboard you can use

```
import javafx.scene.input.Clipboard;
import javafx.scene.input.ClipboardContent;
```

classes for `JavaFX` applications and for example:

```
Clipboard clipboard = Clipboard.getSystemClipboard();
ClipboardContent content = new ClipboardContent();
content.putString("Hello World");
clipboard.setContent(content);
```